# Refactoring website and htaccess (SEO issues)

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

We will refactor a website with about 7000 pages.

Today all pages are in form of

```
http://www.domain.com/locality/id-name-of-the-shop.html
```

Of course the important is the ID, but the locality and name of the shop have some form of "slug" to bypass problem of accented chars (à / è / ì) / umlaut / etc.

We cannot mantain "old style" of links, so I think:

1 - in htaccess first of all I make 301 redirects to .html version to our "no-extension" version ( `http://www.domain.com/locality/id-name-of-the-shop`  )

2 - Sure several link will be different, the links with the accented chars (I presume about the 10-15% of total links). So I'll have two links for same content (e.g. http://www.domain.com/locality/832-metrò and http://www.domain.com/locality/832-metro ). Or, more difficult   http://www.domain.com/l+aquila/5482-name-of-the-shop.html and http://www.domain.com/l-aquila/5482-name-of-the-shop.html

This (for me) drama because I'm using a framework with his slug engine, very powerful, and I would no modify / extend this. Neither I cannot surfing for 7000 pages and write down by hand the redirects :)

Could you give me a hint to proced? Thank you very much and have nice holiday!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "no extension" thing is pretty easy, but the canonicalization of the extended latin characters to the ascii version will be a little more difficult. You're going to need to enumerate them to cover the ones that you expect to have.

```
RewriteEngine On

# no extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/[0-9]+-[^/.]+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect extended latin characters
RewriteRule ^(.*)à(.*)$ /$1a$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)è(.*)$ /$1e$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)ì(.*)$ /$1i$2 [L,R=301]
# etc.

# redirect + to -
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```